# Cannot create a Windows Phone App in Javascript in MS Visual Studio 2013

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to create a new Windows Phone App in JavaScript, however I cannot see that option in the selection even though I meet all the requirements.

I do not have 10 reputation to upload image directly so I have to put here a link to it: [VS 2013 Create Project](http://imageshack.com/a/img838/2088/sl2q.png)

I have Windows 8.1 Pro and Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 Update 2.

[VS 2013 Version](http://imagizer.imageshack.us/a/img836/446/l5a3.png)

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the windows phone 8 SDK. I think you are missing that.

You can download it here https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/downloadsdk

You can try to use phonegap for development

Comment: Yes, I have installed it

Comment: @user3559787 can you see windows phone project option in c#. I am actually a c# developer. If this option is not there then you should check sdk again